# Erratic behavior of dynamic arrays for recursion functions initialized inside and outside for loop

Tags: c++, arrays, for-loop, recursion, dynamic-arrays

I am in a deep trouble that i have not been able to find out why is it happening,
I have a code that is pretty much like

```
int recursion(int ptr[],int i)
{ 
  if(ptr[i]<0) return i;
  return ptr[i] = recursion(ptr,ptr[i]);
}
int main()
{ 
  ....
  int* ptr = new int[N];
  for(int i=0;i<N;i++) ptr[i] = 0;

  for(int i=0;i<25;i++)
  {
    ....
    for(int j=1;j<1000;j++)
    {
     ....
     use recursion function;
    }
   }
  delete [] ptr;
}
```

now this works fine if it is put in like this, the correct code is given [here](https://pastebin.com/YjxvJnhr).

The problem starts when I try to initialize the array inside the loop,

```
int recursion(int ptr[],int i)
{ 
  if(ptr[i]<0) return i;
  return ptr[i] = recursion(ptr,ptr[i]);
}
int main()
{ 
  ....

  for(int i=0;i<25;i++)
  {
    ....
    for(int j=1;j<1000;j++)
    {
     int* ptr = new int[N];
     for(int j=0;j<N;i++) ptr[j] = 0;
     ....
     use recursion function;

     delete [] ptr;
    }
   }

}
```

It is not that it doesnt run, it runs the first time but then gives a segfault for i=2 loop,the code is given here [here](https://pastebin.com/nJ94YJwi)
 , line 244.

I could not figure out why this is happening. Sometimes it runs 2 or 3 loops before giving segfault.

compiled with

```
g++ name.cpp -o name -std=c++14 -O3
```

Comment: My money is on an out of bounds array access. Especially check `ptr[i]`, and make sure `i` is less than `N`.

Comment: What is the question? Please use the debugger to step through the code.

Comment: btw `dynamic array == problems` and those problems have been solved, see `std::vector`

Comment: the question is how to run the code without getting a segfault where the array is initialized inside the loop

Comment: tobi, i have to use array here

Comment: you need to provide a [mcve]. The code you show here certainly does not produce a segfault (it does not compile)

Comment: i have added the code with this question 
https://pastebin.com/nJ94YJwi 
this has error, this is the bottom section.   
https://pastebin.com/YjxvJnhr 
this perfectly runs, this one is the top section, please do check it